# Should I upgrade from Symfony 2.6 to Symfony 4 directly or do it in intermediate stages?

Tags: symfony

We are thinking of upgrading our Symfony app to Symfony 4.

The app is currently on Symfony 2.6 version  (we can upgrade to php 7).

What are the benefits to upgrade through 2 stages from 2.6 to 3 then from 3 to 4 compared with upgrading directly from Symfony 2.6 to Symfony 4?

Comment: There has been quite a bit of evolution between 2.6 and 4.0.  Lots of third party stuff might not have been upgraded.  Lots of tweaks to php itself.  I'd suggest creating a fresh 4.0 project and maybe move a couple of controllers over just to get a feel for what has changed.  You need to at least understand what the final product will look like before deciding.

Answer (score 0):

There are some differences between SF 3.4 and SF 4. So if you have an older Version you should first upgrade to SF 3.4. This is because SF 4 has another structure and use the flex framework. It's possible that you have to change a lot of things during the migration. If you have the time you can do that. If your have Unit-Tests it's much easier to find all the problems.

In general you should read the migration documents that describes the changes in every version and change your code in that way.

https://symfony.com/doc/2.7/setup/upgrade_major.html

So better you upgrade first to version 3.4. Then you have the compatibility to your older code and plugins but no new features that come up in SF 4. But all that depends on the size of your application.

Comment: thanks for the answer. The application is quite large, like 600 classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade, but it will be very painful because the development methodology has changed very much between symfony2 and symfony4. Will better to install separate Symfony 4 project and implement each component of application separate.

Comment: We are currently trying your way. Most of time is spent on autowiring. Sometimes there are some changes on forms (fieldTypes and isSubmitted before isValid) and other things.

Answer (score 0):

You should upgrade by this step:
1 -Symfony2.6 to Symfony2.7
2-  Symfony2.7 to Symfony2.8
3 - Symfony2.8 to Symfony3.4
4- Symfony3.4 to Symfony4